# How to set current row item to previous if smaller, in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

Assume that I have the following `pandas` DataFrame:

```
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 27), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 1.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 30), 1, 0], 
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30), 1, 1.2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 31), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31), 1, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])

        Date  Id  Value
0 2015-01-31   1    0.5
1 2015-02-27   1    2.0
2 2015-03-31   1    1.5
3 2015-04-30   1    0.0
4 2015-05-31   1    2.0
5 2015-06-30   1    1.2
6 2015-07-31   1    3.0
7 2015-08-31   1    0.0
```

I wish for an easy way to loop through `df` and set the current element of `Value` to the previous if it's smaller or equal, and add a Boolean if the element has been changed to the previous. However, I'm at a loss on how to do so. The resulting DataFrame would be:

```
        Date  Id  Value  Altered
0 2015-01-31   1    0.5  False
1 2015-02-27   1    2.0  False 
2 2015-03-31   1    2.0  True
3 2015-04-30   1    2.0  True
4 2015-05-31   1    2.0  True
5 2015-06-30   1    2.0  True 
6 2015-07-31   1    3.0  False
7 2015-08-31   1    3.0  True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cummax()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html) to compute the cumulative maximum of a column.

Store the result of `cummax()` as a temporary variable, compare it with the original column to get the "Altered" column, and then assign it as the new "Value" column:

```
temp = df.Value.cummax()
df['Altered'] = df.Value < temp
df['Value'] = temp
```

This gives:

```
>>> df
        Date  Id  Value Altered
0 2015-01-31   1    0.5   False
1 2015-02-27   1    2.0   False
2 2015-03-31   1    2.0    True
3 2015-04-30   1    2.0    True
4 2015-05-31   1    2.0   False
5 2015-06-30   1    2.0    True
6 2015-07-31   1    3.0   False
7 2015-08-31   1    3.0    True
```

(Note the value at index 4 in "Altered" is False, rather than True, since the value remains `2.0`.)

Comment: Curious question, why does line 4 diff from intended result?

Comment: @deinonychusaur: the value at index 4 remains 2.0 in the cumulative-maximum column: it isn't altered. (Perhaps this is a typo in the OP's expected output.)

Comment: I suppose defining equal to as altered as OP express in text, if that is relevant, makes it a bit trickier.

Comment: @deinonychusaur: If that is the case, it's not clear to me why the values at indices 0 and 1 (which also do not change) are False. Maybe the OP will be able to clarify...

Comment: Thanks! And to answer your question, I'm dealing with mutual fund stuff, which means that I have to calculate performance fees based on "high-water marks"

Comment: @Tingiskhan: no problem! Let me know if this answer is missing any detail  you want and I'll add it in.

Comment: No, it's perfect - exactly what I wanted to accomplish! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `.cummax()` to get max value up-to-date. Compare it with `Value` column to see whether it's been altered.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
     [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 27), 1, 2],
     [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 1.5],
     [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 30), 1, 0], 
     [datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31), 1, 2],
     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30), 1, 1.2],
     [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 31), 1, 3],
     [datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31), 1, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])
df['New_Value'] = df.Value.cummax()
df['Altered'] = df['New_Value'] > df['Value']

print(df)


        Date  Id  Value  New_Value Altered
0 2015-01-31   1    0.5        0.5   False
1 2015-02-27   1    2.0        2.0   False
2 2015-03-31   1    1.5        2.0    True
3 2015-04-30   1    0.0        2.0    True
4 2015-05-31   1    2.0        2.0   False
5 2015-06-30   1    1.2        2.0    True
6 2015-07-31   1    3.0        3.0   False
7 2015-08-31   1    0.0        3.0    True
```